# Passing Javascript variable to php on same page without reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been having problems passing Javascript variable to php using ajax on the same page.I have a try.php page and once a button is clicked, I want a value sent to try.php variable without reloading the page..

This is my form code,I am actually looping trough a database record

```
<?php
foreach($vars as $var){
?>
<form method="POST">
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn_edit" name="btn_edit" value="<?php echo $var['mem_id'];?>">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>

<?php
}
?>
```

Here is my ajax code

```
$('.btn_edit').click(function(e){
    var uid = $(this).val()
    $.post("try.php",{ btn_edit : uid},
        function(){
        });
    console.log(uid);//I could see the id logged on console
    $('#edit_details').modal('show');
    e.preventDefault();//prevent the form from submitting
});
```

On my try.php page, I have this code to check if it passed succesfully

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['btn_edit'])){
        $user_id = $_POST['btn_edit'];
    }?>
```

Comment: Hope my answer will provide you solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are two modifications need to be done:

Change 1: Only input elements can have `value` attribute. And as you have `<button>`, it should be assigned with some other attribute which can be captured using jQuery, so here I am going to use `data-bind` attribute with it.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn_edit" name="btn_edit" data-bind="<?php echo $var['mem_id'];?>">
```

And then,Change 2:
Get data-bind value with jQuery like this:

```
$('.btn_edit').click(function(e){
    var uid = $(this).attr('data-bind');  // Using attr, not val()...
    $.post("try.php",{ btn_edit : uid},
        function(){
        });
    console.log(uid);//I could see the id logged on console
    $('#edit_details').modal('show');
    e.preventDefault();//prevent the form from submitting
});
```

Comment: Thanks i have done that but when i echo $user_id, nothing shows

Comment: Try after removing quotes from data like this : `{ btn_edit : uid}`

Comment: I had written `{ 'btn_edit' : uid}` , notice inverted comma with btn_edit, but I now I am suggesting you to remove them and updated code will be: `{ btn_edit : uid} `

Comment: Where are you checking for `user_id` and can you tell me what data is being sent to php? Can you paste the values being passed in network tab of browser's console?

Comment: @Muhammed, It is very difficult to show you to debug things here in comments, but still, do one thing, in very first line of your php file inside php tag, put this line and see what it shows, `print_r($_POST);die;` and please tell me where are you looking to see the php result? Hope you are looking at network tab of `inspect element` (developer console ) of chrome.You should check its `Network` tab.

Comment: I just did that, its an empty array

Comment: which means ajax is not really posting the variable name btn_edit to the page

Comment: Here is the exact example like your code: [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post2)

Comment: The console still showed the correct value,it means Javascript variable uid has the value, but its not passing to php.

Comment: @ Himanshu Upadhyay  what im trying to do is that once a button is clicked, a variable javascript variable uid is created with value from the button,and a POST request is sent to the **same page** and then caught with a php variable on that same page without reload.